# PyMongo Bulk Insert Runs out of memory

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to write a large HDF5 files into MongoDB.  I'm following the example in this tutorial: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/bulk.html.  I have a generator that loops through each row of the HDF file and yields a dictionary:

```
def gen():
    for file in files:
        data = load_file(file)
        for row in data:
            ob = dict()

            ob['a'] = int(row['a'])
            ob['b'] = int(row['b'])
            ob['c'] = int(row['c'])
            ob['d'] = row['d'].tolist()
            ob['e'] = row['e'].tolist()
            ob['f'] = row['f'].tolist()
            ob['g'] = row['g'].tolist()

            yield ob

def main():
    data = gen()
    db = pymongo.MongoClient().data_db
    db.data.insert(data)
```

This works fine but as time goes on, the Python process takes up more and more RAM until it reaches 10GB and threatens to use up all memory.  I think PyMongo is buffering this data in memory and as it waits to write it to the database.  Is there a way I can limit how big this buffer is instead of letting it grow uncontrollably?  It's strange how the default settings would cause me to run out of RAM.

Comment: Do you see what pocess is using all the memory? MongoDB will ask for as much memory as allowed by the OS; taking into consideration that an OS will not "reuse" RAM until it fills it and requires to page in new data it could just be the normal workings of your OS.

Comment: As for controlling MongoDB (which is not really recommended) you can use ulimit: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/

Comment: @Sammaye It's python (6.9GB) and mongod (3.1GB) that is using the memory.  I have a 16GB system.

Comment: Odd, python is supposed to be good with memory. Well I do not yet know enough about python internals to tell you the answer, I am still learning it myself, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

PyMongo *is* designed to work the way you want: it iterates your generator until it has one batch of data (16 or 32MB, depending on MongoDB version). [Someone contributed this ability to PyMongo last year](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/pull/208). What MongoDB and PyMongo versions are you using?